# Add prefix to value in nested list of dicts

Tags: ansible

I would like to add to this nested list of dictionaries prefix in the `name` of the `members`:

```yaml
    pool:
      - name: "OPENSTACK_POC_POOL_KEYSTONE_SERVICE"
        port: 5000
        members:
          - name: "OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL01_OPENS_KEYSTONE_CONTAINER_097AD5B5"
            host: 10.5.1.2
          - name: "OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL02_OPENS_KEYSTONE_CONTAINER"
            host: 10.5.3.3
          - name: "OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL03_OPENS_KEYSTONE_CONTAINER"
            host: 10.3.1.7
        state: present
    
      - name: "OPENSTACK_POC_POOL_CINDER_API"
        port: 8776
        members:
          - name: "OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL01_OPENS"
            host: 10.5.2.9
          - name: "OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL02_OPENS"
            host: 10.3.2.168
          - name: "OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL03_OPENS"
            host: 10.3.1.6
        state: present
```

That will be like that:

```yaml
pool:
  - name: "OPENSTACK_POC_POOL_KEYSTONE_SERVICE"
    port: 5000
    members:
      - name: "ANSIBLE-OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL01_OPENS_KEYSTONE_CONTAINER"
        host: 10.5.1.2
      - name: "ANSIBLE-OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL02_OPENS_KEYSTONE_CONTAINER"
        host: 10.5.3.3
      - name: "ANSIBLE-OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL03_OPENS_KEYSTONE_CONTAINER"
        host: 10.3.1.7
    state: present

  - name: "OPENSTACK_POC_POOL_CINDER_API"
    port: 8776
    members:
      - name: "ANSIBLE-OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL01_OPENS"
        host: 10.5.2.9
      - name: "ANSIBLE-OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL02_OPENS"
        host: 10.3.2.168
      - name: "ANSIBLE-OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL03_OPENS"
        host: 10.3.1.6
    state: present
```

I have more ways that I tried to reach it but I will show you my last version.

I tried this one, however since there are two `name` keys, it ignores one of them:

```yaml
- set_fact:
   data2: "{{ data.members |combine({'name': 'ANSIBLE-' }) }}"
- name: with_nested
  set_fact:
    data2: [{'name': "{{item.0.name}}", 'members': [{'host': "{{item.1.host}}"}]}]
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ data }}"
    - "members"
  register: test

- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.members.0.name | regex_replace('^.*', 'a\\1') }}"
  loop: "{{ data | ansible.utils.remove_keys(target=['monitor']) }}"
```

The idea is to combine them and change the name with the prefix to a new dict, but I still couldn't figure it out.
I am using Ansible version 2.13.1, so a map update cannot be used here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the names. Declare the variables

```yaml
  pool_names: "{{ pool|json_query(pool_names_query) }}"
  pool_names_query: "[].{members: members[].{name: ['ANSIBLE', name].join('-',@),
                                             host: host}}"
```

give

```yaml
  pool_names:
  - members:
    - host: 10.5.1.2
      name: ANSIBLE-OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL01_OPENS_KEYSTONE_CONTAINER_097AD5B5
    - host: 10.5.3.3
      name: ANSIBLE-OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL02_OPENS_KEYSTONE_CONTAINER
    - host: 10.3.1.7
      name: ANSIBLE-OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL03_OPENS_KEYSTONE_CONTAINER
  - members:
    - host: 10.5.2.9
      name: ANSIBLE-OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL01_OPENS
    - host: 10.3.2.168
      name: ANSIBLE-OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL02_OPENS
    - host: 10.3.1.6
      name: ANSIBLE-OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL03_OPENS
```

Combine the update

```yaml
  pool_update: "{{ pool|zip(pool_names)|map('combine')|list }}"
```

gives the updated pool

```yaml
  pool_update:
  - members:
    - host: 10.5.1.2
      name: ANSIBLE-OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL01_OPENS_KEYSTONE_CONTAINER_097AD5B5
    - host: 10.5.3.3
      name: ANSIBLE-OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL02_OPENS_KEYSTONE_CONTAINER
    - host: 10.3.1.7
      name: ANSIBLE-OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL03_OPENS_KEYSTONE_CONTAINER
    name: OPENSTACK_POC_POOL_KEYSTONE_SERVICE
    port: 5000
    state: present
  - members:
    - host: 10.5.2.9
      name: ANSIBLE-OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL01_OPENS
    - host: 10.3.2.168
      name: ANSIBLE-OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL02_OPENS
    - host: 10.3.1.6
      name: ANSIBLE-OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL03_OPENS
    name: OPENSTACK_POC_POOL_CINDER_API
    port: 8776
    state: present
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    pool:
      - name: "OPENSTACK_POC_POOL_KEYSTONE_SERVICE"
        port: 5000
        members:
          - name: "OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL01_OPENS_KEYSTONE_CONTAINER_097AD5B5"
            host: 10.5.1.2
          - name: "OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL02_OPENS_KEYSTONE_CONTAINER"
            host: 10.5.3.3
          - name: "OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL03_OPENS_KEYSTONE_CONTAINER"
            host: 10.3.1.7
        state: present
      - name: "OPENSTACK_POC_POOL_CINDER_API"
        port: 8776
        members:
          - name: "OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL01_OPENS"
            host: 10.5.2.9
          - name: "OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL02_OPENS"
            host: 10.3.2.168
          - name: "OPENSTACK_ECPOCMCTL03_OPENS"
            host: 10.3.1.6
        state: present

    pool_names: "{{ pool|json_query(pool_names_query) }}"
    pool_names_query: "[].{members: members[].{name: ['ANSIBLE', name].join('-',@),
                                               host: host}}"
    pool_update: "{{ pool|zip(pool_names)|map('combine')|list }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: pool_names
    - debug:
        var: pool_update
```